# C# Sending Email - Sanity check

Tags: c#, email

Sanity check of an email implementation please :-) Anything obvious I've missed?

```
string supplierOfThisMaterialEmailAddress = "davexxx@gmail.com"; // TODO


string htmlBodyIncludingReplacements = "<html><head><title>E-mail</title></head><body><div>.  There has been a request on the hello.co.nz website for: " + txtMaterialDescription.Text +
            "<br />Full Name: <b>" + fullName + "</b><br />" +
            etc..";

        string textOnlyBodyIncludingReplacements = "E-mail.  There has been a request on the freematerials.co.nz website for: " + txtMaterialDescription.Text +
            "Full Name: " + fullName +
            "etc..";

        string subject = "Someone has contacted you";

        CustomMailer mailer = new CustomMailer();
        string result = mailer.SendEmail(subject, htmlBodyIncludingReplacements, supplierOfThisMaterialEmailAddress, textOnlyBodyIncludingReplacements);
        if (result != null)
            lblMessage.Text = result;
        else
            lblMessage.Text = "Thank you - email has been sent";
```

And the class:

```
public class CustomMailer
    {
        public string SendEmail(string subject, string htmlBodyIncludingReplacements, string emailTo, string textOnlyBodyIncludingReplacements)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress sender = new MailAddress("dave@hello.co.nz", "Dave Mateer");
                emailTo = "dave@hello.co.nz"; // testing
                MailAddress recipient = new MailAddress(emailTo, null);

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(sender, recipient);
                message.Subject = subject;

                AlternateView textView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(textOnlyBodyIncludingReplacements, null, "text/plain");
                AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBodyIncludingReplacements, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
                message.AlternateViews.Add(textView);
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Send(message);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? nothing happening, error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, catching a general Exception object and throwing a new one is going to have the net effect of eating any exceptions thrown by `SendEmail`.

The rest looks okay.

Comment: Many thanks everyone -  wanted a sanity checked that I hadn't missed anything obvious in emailling.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the 
`catch (Exception ex)
 {
                throw new Exception();
            }`
to :

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

because otherwise you lose all the data that came with the original excepion that was thrown

Comment: ...or just remove the catch block